# How do you install a GUI on Ubuntu Server in Google Compute Engine (GCE)?

Tags: 14.04, server, xorg, lxde, google

I deployed an Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS Virtual Machine (VM) in the Google Compute Engine. However, I am unable to make the GUI to start. I followed all the steps found in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI, but nothing worked.

I would like to install LXDE for my server but it is very hard to make it work. When I reboot the machine it loads Ubuntu Server in Command Line and when I run `sudo startx`, I get following error:

```
Loading extension GLX
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

I am also thinking that the problem could be related with the fact that It does not ask me to log in. And when I `sudo` it does not ask me for a password.

Comment: Starting the GUI directly won't work in a cloud environment. If you must use a GUI on a remote system, you have to use X forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

You can install VNCserver, I use the following link. Hope it helps http://www.namhuy.net/3106/install-vnc-server-ubuntu-14-04.html

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, Could please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/599253/edit) your answer to explain the contents from the link? The internet changes and if it is later removed this answer would help no one, by all means leave it as a source but it is better to explain the process directly on AskUbuntu.